# Define Array in VBA setting step value

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I want to define an array that goes from 0 till 50 with steps of 10. I would look like: `arr = [0;10;20;30;40;50]`

Should be something like

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Array(0:10:50)
```

but this is obviously not working.

Any idea?

Comment: python lover? I'd bet it isn't possible but if it is it'd be useful to me, you have my vote :-)

Comment: Don't understand what you are trying to achieve. So you have an array where you only want to pick every 10th item from the array or you want to create an array with increments of 10?

Comment: I want to create an array with increments of 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill your array with values with a fix increment use the following (change NumElements and Increment to your needed values):

```
Sub FillArray()
Dim I As Integer, Arr() As Long
Const NumElements As Integer = 6
Const Increment As Integer = 10

    ReDim Arr(1 To NumElements)
    For I = 1 To NumElements
        Arr(I) = (I - 1) * Increment
    Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What is "an array with increments of 10"? Do mean to be able to index an array with indices that step by 10, e.g.:

```
Dim arr(0 To 100 Step 10)  '(fictional syntax; has only 11 elements)
For i = 0 To 100 Step 10
    s = arr(i)
Next i
```

I don't think that is possible. You can of course take the modulo of your index:

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim arr(0 To 10)
For i = 0 To 100 Step 10
    s = arr(i/10)
Next i
```